# Skip parent if using PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

Not sure if this is even possible, but the basic idea of the code is as follows:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if($_POST['field'] == 0) {
        // do not process the code in the if statement
    }
    // code to process if the above validation criteria is not met
}
```

I basically want to try and keep it as simple as possible without lots of if's everywhere, just the quick validation statements at the top, and if none of those if statements are triggered, it will process the code to update the database etc.

I have tried the `continue` statement function with no joy, I believe that only works with loops.

Thanks!

Comment: You could put all of this in a function and then call 'return' from the inside 'if'.

Comment: Okay, I've just created a validateForm() function, and changed my initial statement to if(isset($_POST['submit']) && validateForm() == true) - I like this solution a lot, thank you! Please submit as an answer if you get a chance ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put all of this in a function and then call 'return' from the inside 'if':

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && validate_form())
{
    ...
}

function validate_form()
{
    if($_POST['field'] == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    if(another check that fails) {
        return false;
    }
    ...
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Aleks, there are some great alternative solutions on here, but this is the one I went with in the end, with great results!

Answer (score 4):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['field'] != 0) {

}
```

As a function

```
function testCondition() {
   return isset($_POST['submit']) && 
          $_POST['field'] != 0;
}

if (testCondition()) { ... }
```

Comment: Ah, thank you! I guess this probably is the best way around it then, just a shame if there's a _lot_ of validation checks to perform, but right now there are only 8 or so. Thanks again :-)

Comment: you can combine them before hand in a method.

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this as you originally desired, you need to use the `break` statement.  [From the PHP manual](http://php.net/break):

```
$arr = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'stop', 'five');
while (list(, $val) = each($arr)) {
    if ($val == 'stop') {
        break;    /* You could also write 'break 1;' here. */
    }
    echo "$val<br />\n";
}

/* Using the optional argument. */

$i = 0;
while (++$i) {
    switch ($i) {
    case 5:
        echo "At 5<br />\n";
        break 1;  /* Exit only the switch. */
    case 10:
        echo "At 10; quitting<br />\n";
        break 2;  /* Exit the switch and the while. */
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```